# Enable Failed Tracing in IIS 8.0

Tags: iis

I am getting a HTTP 500 error when trying to run my website.  To try and figure out what is going on I want to turn on Failed Request Tracing Rules.

I am going off of these instructions https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/tracefailedrequestslogging

and everything is fine until I get to Step 3 of HOW TO CONFIGURE THE FAILED REQUEST TRACING SETTINGS FOR A SITE.  This step is simple enough "In the site's Home pane, click Failed Request Tracing... in the Actions pane." except that isn't there in my action pane.  In fact the entire config section isn't there in the Actions Pane.  So I either need another way to enable Failed Request Tracing, or a way to get this configure section of the action pane there.

[My IIS view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjVvS.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Click on "Open Feature" in the top right then click "Add" to add a new  rule